# Considerations for ASP.NET application with long running synchronous requests

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-7, long-running-processes

Under windows server 2008 64bit, IIS 7.0 and .NET 4.0 if an ASP.NET application (using ASP.NET thread pool, synchronous request processing) is long running (> 30 minutes). Web application has no page and main purpose is reading huge files ( > 1 GB) in chunks (~5 MB) and transfer them to the clients. Code:

```
while (reading)
{
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Single producer - single consumer pattern implemented so for each request there are two threads. I don't use task library here but please let me know if it has advantage over traditional thread creation in this scenario. HTTP Handler (.ashx) is used instead of a (.aspx) page. Under stress test CPU utilization is not a problem but with a single worker process, after 210 concurrent clients, new connections encounter time-out. This is solved by web gardening since I don't use session state. I'm not sure if there's any big issue I've missed but please let me know what other considerations should be taken in your opinion ?

*for example maybe IIS closes long running TCP connections due to a "connection timeout" since normal ASP.NET pages are processed in less than 5 minutes, so I should increase the value.*

I appreciate your Ideas.

Comment: I asked a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007863/how-to-create-threads-in-asp-net-pages-from-clr-thread-pool-instead-of-asp-net-pool   but still unanswered.

Comment: Unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't allow to set a bounty on a question from first day. You see here after some edit here are some answers with no relation to edit. Any new answer has a more chance for acception.

Comment: On WAWS, you can use Azure WebJobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Web-Gardening for more stability of your application.

Turn-off caching since you don't have aspx pages

It's hard to advise more without performance analysis. You the VS built-in and find the bottlenecks.

Comment: Gardening is not a solution for long running processes. You posted a good question, this is not a good answer. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would be looking at a different mechanism for this type of processing.  HTTP Requests/Web Applications are NOT designed for this type of thing, and stability is going to be VERY hard, you have a number of risks that could cause you major issues as you are working with this type of model.

I would move that processing off to a backend process, so that you are OUTSIDE of the asp.net runtime, that way you have more control over start/shutdown, etc.

Comment: Send the file, not have a page send the file.....that would be my first item.  I would need to know what exactly you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

First,  Never.  NEVER.  NEVER! do any processing that takes more than a few seconds in a thread pool thread.  There are a limited number of them, and they're used by the system for many things.  This is asking for trouble.

Second, while the handler is a good idea, you're a little vague on what you mean by "generate on the fly"  Do you mean you are encrypting a file on the fly and this encryption can take 30 minutes?  Or do you mean you're pulling data from a database and assembling a file?  Or that the download takes 30 minutes to download?

Edit:

As I said, don't use a thread pool for anything long running.  Create your own thread, or if you're using .NET 4 use a Task and specify it as long running.

Answer (score 1):

Long running processes should not be implemented this way. Pass this off to a service that you set up.

IF you do want to have a page hang for a client, consider interfacing from AJAX to something that does not block on IO threads - like node.js.

Push notifications to many clients is not something ASP.NET can handle due to thread usage, hence my node.js. If your load is low, you have other options.

Comment: This is a download website. What you suggest for large binary responses ? (see edit please)

Answer (score 0):

The Web 1.0 way of dealing with long running processes is to spawn them off on the server and return immediately.  Have the spawned off service update a database with progress and pages on the site can query for progress.

The most common usage of this technique is getting a package delivery.  You can't hold the HTTP connection open until my package shows up, so it just gives you a way to query for progress.  The background process deals with orchestrating all of the steps it takes for getting the item, wrapping it up, getting it onto a UPS truck, etc.  All along the way, each step is recorded in the database.  Conceptually, it's the same.

Edit based on Question Edit:  Just return a result page immediately, and generate the binary on the server in a spawned thread or process.  Use Ajax to check to see if the file is ready and when it is, provide a link to it.