# How to create threads in ASP.NET pages from CLR thread pool instead of ASP.NET pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, clr, threadpool

If I create a new thread on an ASP.NET page the `IsThreadPoolThread` property is true.
First question is, is it from ASP.NET pool or CLR pool ?
Second question is, if it is from ASP.NET pool then how to create a thread from CLR and don't use ASP.NET pool ?
I need a synchronous solution for long-running requests ([full story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006561/download-server-with-asp-net-how-to-accomplish-long-running-synchronous-requests)).

Answer (score 8):

First off, there is no difference between the ASP.NET thread pool and the CLR thread pool.  ASP.NET processes pages on the CLR thread pool, so your ASP.NET pages will always have IsThreadPoolThread == true.

I'm curious as to how you are creating your thread.  Are you using the System.Threading.Thread constructor, or are you using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?  If you are using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, then the threads that you are getting are coming from the regular .net thread pool.

Finally, as I have [posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818154/thread-in-asp-net-c/4818391#4818391), it is always a bad idea to attempt long running tasks from within ASP.NET.  My general suggestion is to use a background windows service to process these requests, since ASP.NET may terminate your background thread at any point.  More details [here, if you must do it in IIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310001335/http://csharpfeeds.com/post/5415/Dont_use_the_ThreadPool_in_ASP.NET.aspx).

Comment: Surely constructing a new Thread manually from asp.net would not result in IsThreadPoolThread being set to true, right?  So he must be calling QueueUserWorkItem.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Right, I was just asserting for my own sanity.

Comment: For those threads IsThreadPoolThread should be false.  Are you sure it is returning true?

Comment: Here are some more: http://dotnetkicks.com/aspnet/Don_t_use_the_ThreadPool_in_ASP_NET http://madskristensen.net/post/Done28099t-use-the-ThreadPool-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 4):

While there is a point to be made about minimizing impact on transactions and catering for the unforeseen in distributed transactions, in this example its really not necessary to reinvent IIS just because the process is long running. The whole "IIS can die at any moment" meme is IMHO greatly exaggerated.

Yes, you can manually restart IIS or app pool but so can you restart any other service which does the same job for the same effect. As for auto-recycle IIS uses overlapping worker processes and will never terminate a started thread forcefully (unless time out occurs). If that were the case we would have serious problems with any hosted application (what's to stop IIS from killing a fast response thread 0.001ms after start)

In essence, let the IIS do what IIS does best and don't insist on sync operation, you'll just waste pool's thread waiting for blocking I/O which is what I believe you are trying to avoid. You already made a good choice by going to Asynchronous Handlers (ASHX), use `IHttpAsyncHandler` implementation to spawn your custom thread which will then block to your heart's desire without affecting the web application and its pool. Once you initiate an async operation thread the asp.net thread will go back to its own pool and will be ready to start serving a new request. With a default limit of 100 threads in a pool and given that your process is low-on-cpu-high-on-bandwidth I doub't you'll ever run out of pool threads before you run out of pipe space :). For more information on how to build async handler check this link (its an old article but valid non the less):

[Use Threads and Build Asynchronous Handlers in Your Server-Side Web Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a difference in threads in ASP .NET: Worker threads and IO threads (system threads which i believe you state as CLR thread).

Now ASP .NET use a worker thread on each request, unless custom configurations are used, and these worker threads are limited on your CPU number; this configuration can be set in IIS.
When you start an asynchronous task inside ASP.NET by using delegate for instance, you are using another worker thread. Delegates are a quick and dirty way of starting something asynchronous in .NET :)

If you want to start a new thread which does NOT use up a worker thread, then you must explicitly start a new thread like: new Thread()....etc. Now this comes with alot code management, and does not follow the event based asynchronous pattern.
However there is one way you can start asynchronous threads safely and that is by using .NETs own asynch methods on objects. Things you normally would use asynch for like SQL commands, webservice calls, etc. All these have a BEGIN and an END method. 
By using these methods you will never use a worker thread, but an IO thread.

ASP .NET has a few tricks up its sleeve when it comes to asynchronous pages.
There are two alternatives:

1. Asynchronous page: which lets your page cycle to be asyncronous. This basicly means      that the page is requested asynchronous.
2. Asynchronous page tasks: which lets you define tasks that will fire asynchronous when the page starts. Its kinda like Asynch threads, just that ASP .NET does alot of things for you, and its more restricted.

I dont have all the details, but please look into the two options on MSDN Library.
Here is an article on the subject: [asynch programmin](http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/net-worker-threads-io-threads-and-asynchronous-programming/)